# ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API returns 404 error when the data exists and return proper message if the result is blank

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi

Using mongodb/.NET Core 6
API end point returns 404 if the data exists and gives right error message when there is no data. I know it's something to do with Json Conversion below is my controller

```
[HttpPost("FilterUsers")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> gUsersFiltered([FromBody] gFilterRequest gr)
    {
        if (gr.Key.Equals("Email"))
        {
            var users = await Task.Run(() => _gRepo
           .FilterBy(x => x.Email.Equals(gr.Value)).AsQueryable());
            return Ok(users);
        }
     }
```

One of the property is of type dynamic. And it kicks out exactly at the "get;" of that property.

```
[BsonElement("UserDocument")]
public dynamic UserDocument { get; set; };
```

No error/exception or trace; JsonConversion or serialization might be the problem.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does it returns expected result if you remove `UserDocument`?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, Yes you are right... it returns the list without the UserDocument. I narrowed it down to the problem associated with dynamic field

Comment: Thanks for your response, I hope it helped to narrow down your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This one, I solved it by changing dynamic to ExpandoObject.. and few more small adjustment due to this change in type.

```
    [BsonElement("UserDocument")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public ExpandoObject UserDocument { get; set; };
```